# Как сделать проверку прав человека по нажатию на кнопку?

Tags: python, discord, nextcord

Пытаюсь сделать код, когда человек нажимает на кнопку у него сначала проверяют, если ли у него права администратора. Если они есть написать один текст, если нет другой. Но задался вопросом, как это делать?
Мой код

```
member = interaction.user
adm = nextcord.Permissions(administrator = True)
if adm in member.guild_permissions is None:
     await interaction.response.send_message('нет')
else:
     await interaction.response.send_message('+')
```

Буду рад вашей помощи!

Answer (score 0):

Проверку можно сделать таким образом:

```
if interaction.user.guild_permissions.administrator:
```

Оно возвращает значения `True`/`False`.